# Atomicity of the semidomain (under Dirichlet convolution) of arith. fncs to a subrig of the ring of integers of a totally real NF

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $S$ be a non-trivial sub[semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Definition) of the ring of integers of a totally real number field, and denote by $D_S$ the integral semidomain of all arithmetic functions $\mathbf N^+ \to S$ with the operations of pointwise addition and [Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution). It is clear that $D_S$ is atomic (respectively, factorial) only if so is $S$, and my questions are somehow on the converse of this statement:

> **Q1.** Is there any case at all in which $D_S$ is atomic (respectively, factorial)? Is there anything in the literature about that?

I'm especially interested in the case when $S$ is a ring, and don't even know the answer for $S = \mathbf Z$.

Let me recall that an integral semidomain is *atomic* if every non-zero, non-unit element is a (finite) product of atoms (irreducible elements) in at least one way, and *factorial* if every non-zero, non-unit element can be expressed as a product of atoms in an essentially unique way.

> **Q2.** What about the atomicity of the subrig of $D_S$ consisting of finitely supported arithmetic functions?

Comment: I see I got a negative vote (counterbalanced by a subsequent positive one). It is hard to divine why without a comment by the voter, but I've tried to guess and improve the post.

Comment: Regarding Q1 and factoriality, see this 1963 paper of Cashwell and Everett: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103035955